# Requested registry access is not allowed on remote box

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, registry

We have developed a somewhat diffuse system for handling component installation and upgrades across server environments in an automated manner. It worked happily on our development environment, but I've run into a new problem I've not seen before when attempting to deploy it to a live environment.

The environment in question comprises ten servers, five each on two different geographical sites and domains. Each server runs a WCF based windows service that allows it to talk to each of the other servers and thus keep a track of what's installed where. To facilitate this process we make use of machine level environment variables - and modifying these obviously means registry changes.

Having got all this set up, my first attempts to use the system to install stuff seemed to work, but on one box in particular I'm getting "Requested registry access is not allowed" errors when the code tries to modify the environment variables. I've googled this, obviously, but there seem to be a variety of different causes and I'm really not sure which are the applicable ones. It doesn't help that this is a live environment and that our system has relatively limited internal logging capability.

The only clue I've got is that the guy who did the install on the development boxes wrote a very patch set of documentation on the process. This includes an instruction to modify the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy value in the registry and set it to 1. I skipped this during the installation as it looked like a rather dubious security risk. Reading the documentation about this key, it looks relevant but my initial attempts at installing stuff on other boxes without this setting enabled worked fine. Sadly the author went on extended leave over the holidays yesterday and he left no explanation of why this key was needed, so we're a bit in the dark.

Can anyone help us toward the light?

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error when code tries to write to the event log using something like EventLog.WriteEntry() and a source that is not a registered event source is specified.  When a source is specified that has not previously been registered, it will attempt to register the source, which involves writing to the registry.

I would suggest taking a look at SysInternals Process Monitor:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

You can use this to monitor registry access and find out what key you're getting the access denied error on.  This may give you some insight as to what is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly there are just too many reg functions going on for Process Monitor to be able to isolate the problem one. But it could be logging that's responsible rather than environment vars - both are happening in the code block where it's failing.

Comment: OK, I managed to track it down. It is the environment variables. Not sure how much that helps though :)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially he's disabling part of the Remote User Account Control. Without setting the value, Remote UAC strips administrative privileges from account tokens remotely accessing the machine. Yes, it does have security implications. See [Description of User Account Control and remote restrictions in Windows Vista](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951016) for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks. I've pretty much ruled this out as being connected to this particular issue, which is something of a relief.